# Oracle SQL to compare data and retrieve un-matching rows between two tables in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, informatica

I am trying to compare the data between two tables using Oracle SQL. The SQL must compare the data and must return the non-matching data from the table. Does anyone have any idea to perform this operation? I might do this using SQL or use Informatica for performing the same. Please do help me out. Thanks in advance.

NOTE:They might have the same structure since I will be creating a TEMP table A with ID, Qty,Price. A will be compared with B (ID, Qty,Price). A is from EBS and TEMP A is created in Oracle. B is from Data-warehouse and exists in Oracle DB.

Comment: Do the tables have the same fields?  Table schema, sample data and desired results can be helpful.

Comment: Yes they might have the same structure since I will be creating a TEMP table A with ID, Qty,Price. A will be compared with B (ID, Qty,Price). A is from EBS and TEMP A is created in Oracle. B is from Data-warehouse and exists in Oracle DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare rows from 2 tables using sets: take the union of both tables and subtract from it the intersection of them.

```
(
select id, qty, price from table_a
union
select id, qty, price from table_b
)
minus
(
select id, qty, price from table_a
intersect
select id, qty, price from table_b
);
```

That will give you what rows do not match the opposite table, but you won't be able to tell from that query what row came from which table. That should be easy to get, joining the result with the original table (or intersect again, although join should be cheaper given the table has a primary key).

```
with t as (
(
select id, qty, price from table_a
union
select id, qty, price from table_b
)
minus
(
select id, qty, price from table_a
intersect
select id, qty, price from table_b
))
select *
  from t
  join table_a a on t.id = a.id;
```

Same will work joining table_b, for finding out what rows there don't match table_a.

Running sample:

```
SQL> create table table_a (id number, qty number, price number);
Table created
SQL> insert into table_a values (1, 100, 1.1);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into table_a values (2, 200, 2.2);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into table_a values (3, 300, 3.3);
1 row inserted
SQL> create table table_b (id number, qty number, price number);
Table created
SQL> insert into table_b values (1, 100, 1.1);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into table_b values (2, 200, 2.2);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into table_b values (4, 300, 3.3);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into table_b values (5, 500, 5.5);
1 row inserted
SQL> (
  2  select id, qty, price from table_a
  3  union
  4  select id, qty, price from table_b
  5  )
  6  minus
  7  (
  8  select id, qty, price from table_a
  9  intersect
 10  select id, qty, price from table_b
 11  );
        ID        QTY      PRICE
---------- ---------- ----------
         3        300        3,3
         4        300        3,3
         5        500        5,5
SQL> with t as (
  2  (
  3  select id, qty, price from table_a
  4  union
  5  select id, qty, price from table_b
  6  )
  7  minus
  8  (
  9  select id, qty, price from table_a
 10  intersect
 11  select id, qty, price from table_b
 12  ))
 13  select *
 14    from t
 15    join table_a a on t.id = a.id;
        ID        QTY      PRICE         ID        QTY      PRICE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3        300        3,3          3        300        3,3

SQL>
```